# Writing file from byte[] in android fails

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm writing an app which must send some files via bluetooth.
A client recieves a byte array which must be then constructed into file. But only a few lines from array are copied into the file!
Here's my code from thread, where every message from server is read:

Edit: try/catch code.

```
try {   
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("//mnt//sdcard//" + fileName);    
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("FAIL", e.toString());
    }
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("FAIL", e.toString());
}
```

Buffer is byte[]. I even checked with Toast: everything is fine with buffer. It contains every symbol from file, but I can't write it all somehow.

Comment: can you elaborate on 'can't write'?  Do you get an error?  Does it create a 0byte file?  Or nothing?

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving the whole file in `buffer`?

Comment: Creating, writing to, and closing `fos` should throw an Exception if something goes wrong. Wrap your code with a try/catch block and let us know what kind of Exception it catches.

Comment: @dispake I can write to that file. I just can't write everything from file I want to download!

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, I'm pretty sure. The contents of buffer are then displayed with Toast(I compared it's contents with the original file - they match)

Comment: @Dylan This code is surrounded with try/catch block. Exception is not thrown

Comment: Another hunch - if you're using NIO 2, there's some extra pointer wrangling that you have to do when dealing with buffers. Maybe reading the buffer to check that it's all there is actually setting the pointer to the end, so when you try to write from it, it appears empty.

Comment: @Dylan After writing to file I convert byte array to string and show it's contents in String. Everything is fine there

Comment: Did you check the remaining space in the SD?

Comment: Yes. File itself is 4 kb, so it shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example that you could try to use is:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getCacheDir(), FILENAME), false);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
byte[] loginBuffer = new byte[1024];
int byteRead = 0;
while((byteRead = in.read(loginBuffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(loginBuffer, 0, byteRead);
}
out.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never hard code the file paths like you did.

In android, you should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory

```
String fname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "myfile.jpg";
File file = new File( fname );
```

If you don't specify the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory in file path, it will be return in your app installation folder.

In your case, this file might have been written in "com.your.package/test.jpg"

Comment: Well, that was just a test. File was written correctly where it was supposed to write(it was located on my sd card), so problem is not there

Answer (score -1):

trie to tell how much you want to write on the file

fos.write(buffer,0, x);

where x is size of buffer in bytes
and 0 is offset

Answer (score -1):

I think that the most likely culprit is that your app doesn't have write permissions.

See https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card

> You need to add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
>
> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
>
> Note: you with get a `FileNotFoundException` if you try to open/create a file on the SD card when it is mounted on your computer. You must unmount it first before you can access it in your application.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem.
Permissions are okay, file is found and succesfully created but only part of it is written(2.4 of 3.6 kb for example)